# When was the picture of Lockwood's daughter and Maisie taken?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In the movie Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom, when Clair visits Lockwood for the first time at his estate, she sees a little girl and upon asking, Mills tells her that it's Lockwood's granddaughter and also that his daughter is deceased.

Almost by the end of the movie, Mills breaks the news to Owen and Clair that

> Maisie isn't really Lockwood's granddaughter, but instead she's a human clone of Lockwood's deceased daughter.

We also find Maisie looking at a picture that she had stolen from Lockwood which has both Lockwood's daughter and herself in it.

> Was Maisie cloned before Lockwood's daughter dies?

When was this particular picture taken?

Answer (score 10):

You've misunderstood who's in the picture.

The picture is the nanny (a fair bit younger), with Lockwood's daughter, not with Maisie.  It was presumably taken when Lockwood's daughter was Maisie's age.

The girl looks like Maisie, because of course Maisie is a clone of her.  We can infer from the younger nanny that the girl is not Maisie but her "mother".

Note that the nanny foreshadows this fact when she mentions that she "has raised them both".